# How to make all methods from static class available in another static class in c#

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, static

I would like add additional c# methods to a external static class that can't be modified. i.e create a wrapper class for convenience containing the methods of the external static class + my own static methods.

I first wanted to inherit my own class from the external static class but I discover that static classes are sealed and can't be inherited form.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks a lot for you help

Comment: Wrap the external static class methods with your own.

Comment: Just to add to the "pro"s of a wrapper: If the external lib has a breaking change in the static API, there is a high probability you'll need to change only 1 place in your code to accomodate.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Is this the only way? my external library has hundreds of methods and I rather not create wrapper methods for each one of them...

Comment: In that case, don't. Just create your own static class and use both where appropriate. However: (my opinion) a static class with "hundreds of methods" is a pretty strong code smell in my book, anyway ... and leads me to the next question: Are you using _all_ of them? If not, you could just proxy the ones you actually need if that's in a reasonable range.

Comment: Pretty sure you could use Find/Replace to write most of your proxy. Take a look at an editor like Sublime that can put multiple cursors, double click eg `public` on a method call, press Ctrl D repeatedly until all the `public` are highlighted and have their cursor, then just try wrap your head round having multiple cursors that all obey your jeyboard input - if you press SHIFT+END they will ALL go to the end of their line, selecting as they go.. So use the technique to highlight just the method signature lines.. ctrlc/v into..

Comment: .. another file - you'll get a bunch of method signature lines, a hundred cursors.. Start typing `{` - a hundred { appear, keep typing.. `<enter key>` - they all move to the next line, `r` `e` `t` `u` `r` `n` `space` .. `TheirClass.`, `ctrl-v` - now you have all the `return TheirClass.<100 varied mathod names with args>` and so on... You can use interim files/ strip out every `"datatype "` occurrence and access modifier so that `public string SomeMethod(string arg1, string arg2)` becomes `SomeMethod(arg1, arg2)` for easier pasting in after `TheirClass.` etc...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCnSD.gif - https://i1.wp.com/zao.is/wp-content/uploads/multiple-cursors.gif etc. Note one of the most confusing things with multi cursors is: if your document contains 100 cursors and your clipboard contains 100 lines, it maps 1:1 one line per cursor pasted. If there is any difference, every one of 100 cursors pastes every block of eg 99 lines meaning the file gains 9900 lines. When multiple cursors land on top of each other they coalesce to one so if you eg. pressed HOME LEFT HOME the second line cursor and the first line cursor would coalesce to one at line 1 pos 0

Answer (score 4):

Proxy the calls, per Llama's indication

```
public static class YourClass{

  public SomeType TheirMethod(..){
    return TheirClass.TheirMethod(...);
  }

...
```